# Add Web services or WSDL by code C#

Tags: wsdl, axapta

I am new in C# , and want to add WSDL web services by code or dynamically take example i want to add http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/CurrencyService.svc?wsdl by code , without Manually add reference ...
Kindly help me out in this ...thanks

Regards
AMT

Comment: Adding WDSL reference in Visual Studio actually generates code. What you want to do "by code" is actually done for you by Visual Studio and what you can do is to look at the code it generates to figure out if you want to write such code yourself.

Comment: I am working on X++ from where i want to pass a URL to access wsdl , so in that case url could be different but will have same method and parameters .....

Comment: [Same question](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/202642/525098#525098) in AX Community